# Make a dropdown list to select in TextInput

Tags: react-native, dropdown, css-position, react-native-paper, react-native-stylesheet

Im using `react-native-paper` which is a great library, but i ran into a problem when i needed a `dropdown menu`, that is overlay on the `TextInput` field around it.
`Don't want to use any Library` unless it it maintained properly.

```js
  return (
    <View style={{ top: StatusBar.currentHeight }}>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-around',
          marginVertical: 10,
        }}>
        <TextInput
          label={'Title'}
          placeholder={'Mr'}
          value={userinput}
          style={{ width: '30%' }}
          onChangeText={(text) => setUserinput(text)}
          right={<TextInput.Icon icon="chevron-down" size={20} />}
        />
        <TextInput label={'First name'} style={{ width: '60%' }} />
      </View>
      <View style={{ alignSelf: 'center', width: '95%' }}>
        <TextInput
          label={'Phone number'}
          onChangeText={(text) => setUserinput(text)}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

*Currently*
[image: screenshot of the current state.]
*Required*:
[image: Required]

Bare minimum [Expo Snack code](https://snack.expo.dev/@talhamaqsood890/stackoverflow---custom-dropdown?platform=android).

**Already tried**

1. Although `react-native-paper` provides `List` & `List.Accordion` but my problem is not solving by that.
   **issue** When list is open the other text bot field are also extending there height.
2. Mapping function, Flatlist,
   **issue** not getting the results that i want.
3. `Position: Absolute`
   **issue** Mapping is not working accordingly.

Comment: Do you want a picker like the picture shown?

Comment: yes, like the second picture `Required:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using `flatlist` with `zIndex` properties, check my example code

**Example**:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Text, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
    
    const App = () => {
      const [userinput, setUserinput] = useState(null);
      const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
      const openPicker = useCallback(
        () => {
          Keyboard.dismiss()
          setShow(true)
        },
        [show]
      );
    
      const hidePicker = useCallback(
        (item) => {
          setShow(false)
          setUserinput(item)
        },
        [show, userinput]
      );
    
      return (
        <View style={{ top: StatusBar.currentHeight }}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-around',
              marginVertical: 10,
            }}>
            <View style={{ width: '30%' }}>
              <TextInput
                label={'Title'}
                placeholder={show ?'' :'Mr'}
                value={userinput}
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                onChangeText={(text) => setUserinput(text)}
    
                right={<TextInput.Icon onPress={openPicker} icon="chevron-down" size={20} />}
              />
              {show ?
                <FlatList
                  style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgb(211, 211, 211)',elevation:1, zIndex: 22, width: '100%', marginTop: 60, position: 'absolute' }}
                  data={['Mr', 'Mrs', 'Miss']}
                  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => hidePicker(item)}>
                      <Text style={{padding:8}}>
                        {item}
                      </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  )}
                  keyExtractor={item => item}
                />
                : null}
            </View>
            <TextInput label={'First name'} style={{ width: '60%' }} />
          </View>
          <View style={{ alignSelf: 'center', width: '95%', zIndex: -1 }}>
            <TextInput
              label={'Phone number'}
              onChangeText={(text) => setUserinput(text)}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```

Note: `marginTop` will be the same as input `height` and you can also move the flatlist to components

Comment: Yes it worked, now to make it responsive i had to add `<TextInput ....onLayout={e=>{setTextInputHeight(e.nativeEvent.layout.height)}}`  for having ``textInput height``  like this, `marginTop: textInputHeight`. Thank you (: